# emmet for vim: vue files

Tags: vim, emmet

I would like to use the emmet plugin even with .vue files.
What do I need to add into my .vimrc?

I tried with

`autocmd BufEnter,BufNewFile *.vue set ft=html`

I now see the syntax highlight but emmet does not work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest my [leafOfTree/vim-vue-plugin](https://github.com/leafOfTree/vim-vue-plugin). It supports emmet-vim HTML/JavaScript/CSS filetype detection inside `.vue` files. Emmet can be used in `<template>`, `<script>` and `<style>` as well as in HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem. However, how can I tell to my emmet plugin which type of file can I use with it? For example: if I want to use the emmet plugin with files *.example

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can use emmet in any files and define settings for the filetype. See `h g:user_emmet_settings` and https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/5f559fae12a8babf414376906197dbd751e11380/autoload/emmet.vim#L1004 .

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following lines to your .vimrc to enable emmet-vim only for specific file types and add vue to the list:

```
let g:user_emmet_install_global = 0
autocmd FileType html,css,vue EmmetInstall
```